# Connecting to rails console through Railway

Tags: ruby-on-rails, command-line-interface

Hi I have a [railway](https://railway.app/) project set up which has a ruby on rails app running as one of its services.

When I try to run `railway run rails db:seed`, it throws an error that the executable is not found, which I assume means I need to connect to the service through the CLI first before running it, but I can't find any documentation on how to do that. Anyone knows how I can achieve this? Thanks!

Tried running `railway run rails db:seed` but got the error `exec: "rails db:seed": executable file not found in $PATH`.

Was expecting to connect to the rails instance of the service and be able to run `rails` commands.

Answer (score 0):

Realised after looking at the logs they were looking for the executable so I just had to run `railway run bin/rails db:seed` and it worked.